# AWS: Error 504 in communication between ALB internet-facing and ALB internal

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm trying to create a structure in AWS with ECS so that an internet-facing ALB manages traffic to front-end containers and front-end requests go through an internal ALB that forwards to containers with API, but requests to the API are dying in 504.

the ALB facing the internet is configured with listeners that take the host header and forward it to each front, this part is working normally, I did the same for the internal ALB but forwarding it to the API, the containers with API pass the health check, then the service is OK

diagram:
[Cluster Architecture with ALB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEoMk.png)

General structure:

- VPC
- 2 subnets (public and private)
- Internet-facing ALB (with Internet access)
- Internal ALB (inbound rule for VPC only)
- SG on the fronts releasing port for ALB facing the internet
- SG API releasing ports for the internal ALB
- Target groups for each ECS service

If I'm missing any relevant information, I can let you know, thank you in advance!

When I created everything within the same ALB internet-facing works normally

Comment: Access logs from the ALB?

Comment: In the ALB log I have no feedback, it is as if the application had not made the request.

When I place the front and back containers in the same ALB (internet-facing), they communicate

It's as if something is blocking communication, but I've looked in several places to see if there is a problem with my ACL or SG settings and they seem to be OK.

Another detail is that when I create an EC2 within the VPC (on the private or public network) and make a request to the API with curl I get the normal return

Comment: Have you forgot security groups ?

Comment: I didn't forget, I even set permissions for all traffic from anywhere to try and resolve the issue